# Where to define custom error types in Ruby and/or Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conventions

Is there a best practice for defining custom error types in a Ruby library (gem) or Ruby on Rails application? Specifically:

1. Where do they belong structurally in the project? A separate file, inlined with the relevant module/class definition, somewhere else?
2. Are there any conventions that establish when *to* and when *not to* create a new error type?

Different libraries have different ways of doing things, and I haven't noticed any real patterns. Some libraries always use custom error types while others don't use them at all; some have all errors extending StandardError while others have nested hierarchies; some are just empty class definitions, others have all sorts of clever tricks.

Oh, and just because I feel like calling these "error types" is sort of ambiguous, what I mean is this:

```
class AuthenticationError < StandardError; end
class InvalidUsername < AuthenticationError; end
```

Answer (score 238, accepted):

**For Gems**

I have seen many times that you define exceptions in this way:

> gem_dir/lib/gem_name/exceptions.rb

and defined as:

```
module GemName

  class AuthenticationError < StandardError; end
  class InvalidUsername < AuthenticationError; end

end
```

an example of this would be something like this in [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/lib/httparty/exceptions.rb)

**For Ruby on Rails**

Put them in your lib/ folder under a file called exceptions.rb, which would look something like this:

```
module Exceptions
  class AuthenticationError < StandardError; end
  class InvalidUsername < AuthenticationError; end
end
```

and you would use it like this:

```
raise Exceptions::InvalidUsername
```

Comment: For gems, looks like you might have to also include the exception file. See this example, again from `httparty`: https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/5f8f11c0ee899aa66aecf4be06bd9a13e3853d56/lib/httparty.rb#L597

Comment: Why namespace them into the `Exceptions` module?

Comment: I would think that `/lib` might not be the place for errors. They are very application specific and I am under the impression that code that I am putting in `/lib` is meant to be code that could be reused in other applications.

Comment: I'm not sure how I feel about it. But in ruby on rails, I will put them in `app/errors/` folder. However, I do not use the namespace `Errors`

Comment: Ruby on Rails instructions did not work for me -- is some additional step needed to actually load this new file in the typical case?

Comment: @oaamados it's not that is not recommended. Rails 5 just does not autoload it anymore.

Comment: @ABMagil seems I have to otherwise `Unable to autoload constant Exceptions, expected /app/lib/exceptions.rb to define it` the other option would be one class per exception I think

Answer (score 34):

in rails you can make `app/errors` directory

```
# app/errors/foo_error.rb
class FooError < StandardError; end
```

restart spring/server and it should pick it up

Comment: How should I raise these exceptions?

Comment: @NikhilWagh either `raise FooError, "Example message..."` or `raise FooError.new("Example message...")`

Answer (score 27):

I think in order to have cohesive source files in your project, you should define errors in the class in which may throw them and nowhere else.

Some heirarchy can be helpful - namespaces are good at keeping redundant strings out of type names - but that's more a matter of taste - there's no need to go overboard provided you have at least one custom exception type in your app which you use throughout to differentiate between 'intentional' and 'accidental' exception cases.

Comment: While in theory you are right, what happen when the same error can be raised by various classes in totally different situations?

Comment: @Alain Why not define those errors used by more than one class in an Exceptions/Errors module, but leave all others defined in the single class which uses them?

Comment: @ScottW, In that case, we're relying on the developer to remember to check.

Answer (score 21):

This is an old question, but I wanted to share how I'm handling custom errors in Rails, including attaching error messages, testing, and how to handle this with `ActiveRecord` models.

#### Creating Custom Error

```
class MyClass
  # create a custome error
  class MissingRequirement < StandardError; end

  def my_instance_method
    raise MyClass::MissingRequirement, "My error msg" unless true   
  end
end
```

#### Testing (minitest)

```
test "should raise MissingRequirement if ____ is missing"
  # should raise an error
  error = assert_raises(MyClass::MissingRequirement) {
    MyClass.new.my_instance_method
  }

  assert error.message = "My error msg"
end
```

#### With ActiveRecord

I think it's worth noting that if working with an `ActiveRecord` model, a popular pattern is to add an error to the model as described below, so that your validations will fail:

```
def MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :code_does_not_contain_hyphens

  def code_does_not_contain_hyphens
    errors.add(:code, "cannot contain hyphens") if code.include?("-")
  end
end
```

When validations are run, this method will piggy-back onto ActiveRecord's `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` error class and will cause validations to fail.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 12):

To ensure that autoloading works as expected in Rails 4.1.10 for multiple custom error classes, you'll want to specify separate files for each. This should work in development with its dynamically reloading.

This is how I setup errors in a recent project:

In `lib/app_name/error/base.rb`

```
module AppName
    module Error
        class Base < StandardError; end
    end
end
```

and in subsequent custom errors, like in `lib/app_name/error/bad_stuff.rb`

```
module AppName
    module Error
        class BadStuff < ::AppName::Error::Base; end
    end
end
```

You should then be able to call your errors via:

```
 raise AppName::Error::BadStuff.new("Bad stuff just happened")
```

Comment: And if you don't want a separate file for each new error, just put them all in `lib/app_name/error.rb`

Comment: Getting an `uninitialized constant MyController::AppName`. I'm calling raise in my controller

Comment: @NikhilWagh You'll want to prepend the class name with a double colon (::) to ensure it looks in the root namespace for your class.