# Convention for the location of error classes in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Quick question,

I have some ruby classes that extends from StandardError, like:

```
class NotAuthorized < StandarError
end
```

I use this class only to raise exceptions in controllers like this

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :is_admin!

  protected
  def is_admin!
     raise NotAuthorized if ...
  end
end
```

Because the NotAuthorized class is not a model, I do not feel that it should be under model folder. Also is not a controller, though it serves only the controllers. 
Where do you usually put this kind of classes?

Comment: `/lib` folder is one option..generally used for extensions

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200842/where-to-define-custom-error-types-in-ruby-and-or-rails?rq=1 to answer also to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you did not talk about the version of rails that you are using, i will be referring to rails4.

starting with rails 3 (i think) every folder under `app` will get autoloaded. with this in mind, just put stuff where it belongs `app/exceptions` `app/worker` `app/whetever`.

from my perspective, exceptions are a little different. they usually have some kind of context. that's why i like them to be in some module ie `Authorization::NotAuthorized`.

so in my case, there would be a concern named `Authorization` that holds this error class.