# What does this controller code do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've come across this pattern a few times, but am not sure what it is, or how to Google it.

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  class InvalidAppToken < RuntimeError ; end
  class InvalidUserToken < RuntimeError ; end
  ...
end
```

Comment: Mabye you should search how to google.

Comment: @dburner How would you search in this example?

Comment: Given the fact that these are custom errors and you said you found this pattern quite a few times you might want to try "ruby custom errors convention" or "ruby custom errors best practices". And you find this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200842/where-to-define-custom-error-types-in-ruby-and-or-rails

Comment: @dburner That's good advice, thanks. Maybe you should start with that next time.

Comment: Yes I guess you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It creates custom errors. Doing this you can raise your personalized errors, then rescue them to better handle the app errors.

```
class MyController < ApiController
  begin
    unless DoSomething(params[:user_token])
      raise InvalidUserToken
      [...]
    end
  rescue InvalidUserToken
    # manage this error
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good option for searching the web with special symbols considered (most major search engines ignore special characters in searches):

http://symbolhound.com/?q=ruby+%3C+runtimeerror

Answer (score 0):

It simply defines custom types of errors. Could be useful to raise very specific errors in your workflow.

[Have a look at this book](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11799211-exceptional-ruby)