# Ruby exception catch and return false

Tags: ruby, exception

An Exception has been raised in ruby , how can i catch it and return false?

below is the code

```
def function_one
  raise 'exception raised here'
end
```

I have another function from which function_one is being called

```
def function_two
  a = function_one
end
```

I want to catch the exception raised by function_one in such a way that a contains "false".
How can i do it?
please help

Comment: `a = function_one rescue false`

Comment: See the docs on [Exception Handling](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/doc/syntax/exceptions_rdoc.html) – the first actual example shows how to rescue `ZeroDivisionError` in order to return `nil` instead. You can easily adapt that.

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov any exception handling without a specific exception class like for example `rescue false` is an anti-pattern known as pokemon exception handling. You're just creating a black hole that swallows exceptions you should not be rescuing which will make your code buggy and imposible to debug. https://thoughtbot.com/blog/don-t-inline-rescue-in-ruby

Comment: @max sure, but did you check the question before commenting on the answer? `StandardError` is both raised in `function_one` and caught by inline `rescue`. If the code in the initial post would be different (raising more specific error or doing something that could raise a more specific error) my answer would be different too.

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov: my previous comment was too hasty. Still the main point stands: `StandardError` is too wide a net. While SystemStackError is not a StandardError, NoMethodError is (as are many others, You can ignore some of them, but not all).

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov `raise 'exception raised here'` raises a `RuntimeError`, btw.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yep, my bad

Answer (score -1):

We need to define CustomError class in ruby which can be used to raise customer error and handle errors gracefully.

**Please take a look at:**
[Where to define custom error types in Ruby and/or Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200842/where-to-define-custom-error-types-in-ruby-and-or-rails)

If you don't want to create custom error class then you can define function_two like (a simple hack):

```
def function_two
  a = function_one rescue false
end
```